# .gitignore excluir todas as pastas menos uma

Tags: git, github

Preciso fazer que um `.gitignore` exclua do versionamento todas as pastas exceto uma.

Exemplo:

```
Library/nao_ignorar
Library/ignorar
Library/ignorar
Library/ignorar
....
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assim:

```
# Ignore tudo:
*

# Exceto este diretório:

!Library/nao_ignorar Library/
```

O resto será ignorado. Se precisar não ignorar mais diretórios abaixo deste diretório, é necessário especificar os outros diretórios, como por exemplo:

```
# Ignore tudo:
*

# Exceto estes diretórios:

!Library/nao_ignorar Library/
!Library/nao_ignorar Library/*/
!Library/nao_ignorar Library/*/OutroDiretorioNaoIgnorado/
!Library/nao_ignorar Library/*/OutroDiretorioNaoIgnorado/*/*
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá tente o seguinte eu seu .gitignore

```
# Ignorar todos os diretórios e arquivos em um diretório.
tmp/**/*
```

acredito que resolve.

Comment: Diretórios diferencia de linguagem para linguagem na hora de ignorar?

Comment: melhorou chefe?